# Scraping website using beautiful soup returning "None"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run the following code but I keep returning "none". The website I am trying to scrape is dsd.tools.

```
URL = 'https://dsd.tools/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find("div", {"class": "content"})
print(title)
```

It should be simple enough but for some reason I am not able to return the "TWAP price". Let me know what you all think.

Comment: The page is rendered via javascript, you need to use `selenium`

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the response text.

```
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page.text)
```

It seems the element you are looking is not present in response. Maybe the content is being generated at client side using JS.